# Turn Off ActionBar HomeButton for specific fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to disable the home button (left icon) in a particular `fragment`.  I want it there of course, just not clickable. So I am trying to override the parent `Activity` by doing this in `fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem home = menu.findItem(android.R.id.home);
    home.setEnabled(false);

}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Note:  Using `ActionBarSherlock`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get an `ActionBar` instance then disable the home button like so:

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

Comment: OH snap.  I already knew that.  Had a complete brain cramp on that.  Thanks.  Used your exact code so I marked it right (or will when time allows).

Comment: @KickingLettuce happens to all of us :-)

Comment: @KickingLettuce Just to note, that will disable the button, but depending on your ActionBar style, it may still *appear* to be enabled.

Comment: @kcoppock then the OP can also use `setShowHomeAsUpEnabled()`. However, the important thing is the call to `getSherlockActivity()`. `SherlockFragment` doesn't have a `getSupportActionBar()` method.

Comment: Agreed. :) I don't have too much experience with Fragments so that's a good catch.

Comment: I actually do use `setShowHomeAsUpEnabled`.  When this `fragment` opens, I successfully turned that off,  but also wanted to make it **not** clickable.

Answer (score 2):

You should instead use the `ActionBar` to disable that button:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setShowHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```